NextJS vercel/postgres DB query

I have attached the root cause files here

I want to fetch the userrole of the table users and it ain't working via its session, after the user has loggedIn using his email & password. After the userrole is fetched from the Vercel/postgres db I want to conditional render either a logbook or manifest components. Also tried to use CoPilot & Ollama/8b with no success.

Have you tried removing parameter from getUser(). Your definition requires an email parameter.

Hi Dave, thanks for your reply. Do you mean on data.ts row 6? I've now tried that but in row 9 I am querying for "email" in the sql db, hence to my understanding "email" must be defined in the function. What am I missing?

Yes, I mean at data.ts line 6, getUser request for an email parameter but in page.tsx you did not provide. And since your email can be accessed by session,  try replace parameter with const {email} = session?

Hi Dave, yes! Thanks that worked! Solved! Thanks for the help!

Good to hear that, I will post it as an answer if you're willing to accept it as an answer.

Yes, I mean at data.ts line 6, getUser request for an email parameter but in page.tsx you did not provide.
And since your email can be accessed by session, try replace parameter with const {email} = session
